# How could I set up Tank Auth in Code Igniter to handle all login/registration functions at the domain root?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

After a small headache, I got Tank Auth functioning flawlessly on my site.  However, it does all its work via functions in the `auth` controller, and thus displays paths like `site.com/auth/login`,`site.com/auth/register`, etc.

I'd like to be able to handle all of the login and registration/activation related functions without displaying any more than the domain root (`www.site.com`) to the user.  What would be the best way to do this?

Even when I set the `auth` controller as the default controller, it only runs the index function (of course), which then redirects right to `/auth/login/` anyway.

Keep in mind I'm faily new to CI, so there might just be an easy way to do it that I'm not aware of.

I don't recall exactly what version of CI I'm using, but I downloaded it less than a couple of weeks ago, so it's pretty up to date. Same with Tank Auth.

**Update:**

I add entries to the `routes.php` file so that at least the `/auth` part of the URL is no longer there:

```
$route['login'] = '/auth/login';
$route['register'] = '/auth/register';
$route['forgot_password'] = '/auth/forgot_password';
$route['reset_password/(:any)/(:any)'] = '/auth/reset_password';
$route['activate/(:any)/(:any)'] = '/auth/activate';
$route['reset_email/(:any)/(:any)'] = '/auth/reset_email';
```

All of the views/emails/links work as they should, however I'm no longer getting any of the messages associated with actions.  For example, when requesting a password reset, after entering my email, I would normally get a message that says to check my email.  Or, when I register, I would get a message saying I need to activate via email... etc.  I can't quite figure out why I'm not getting these messages any more.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the routes as mentioned in the update to my posted question provided me with an acceptable solution to my original question, but then brought about the problem with the missing messages (also mentioned).  I discovered that this was due to the messages being set as session flashdata, which gets cleared after the next server request.  The re-routing must be causing the flashdata to clear.

I got around this by setting the messages as regular session userdata instead of flashdata, and then manually clearing it after it is displayed.

This seems to be an acceptable solution.